# SQLSTATE[01003]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation

Tags: sql-server, laravel, laravel-5.4, sql-server-2014

I am trying to run the following code

```
DB::table('gbb_intimation_claim_max_serial')->where('id', 1)->increment('intimation_max_serial');
$intimation_max_serial = DB::table('gbb_intimation_claim_max_serial')->where('id', 1)->value('intimation_max_serial');
DB::table('claims')->where('id', $claim->id)->update(['intimation_number' => $intimation_max_serial]);
```

But weirdly, I am getting this error on laravel

```
SQLSTATE[01003]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation. (SQL: update [claims] set [intimation_number] = 1763 where [id] = 7172)
```

I have tried

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
```

But this didn't help

Comment: It's a warning. This causes an error in Laravel?

Comment: Yes. It does @TT

Comment: It seems like the issue is already solved... I am puzzled though that a SQL Server warning would cause an error in Laravel. Perhaps you have a switch/option somewhere to treat warnings as errors (I know nothing about Laravel). This particular warning is really benign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not normally get that error on an update statement, I suspect it is a carryover from your first query where it looks like your are returning the max claim serial, if you look at your data you will find one of the claim serial values is null and when you perform an aggregate function on a range of values that include a null that warning is thrown.

Comment: Your are right. When I re-ran my migrations, the problem was gone. The problem occurred when I tried to create an update trigger without checking for NULL values.